# How to sent an alert / e-mail to user when a particular list item is selected?

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I am using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation. I have a list setup that multiple departments access and update as orders move through production. Orders get entered and assigned to a user (the salesperson) responsible for that particular project, then they can check on the status of their order from entry, purchasing, production, quality control, etc.

What I would like to do is when the shipping department modifies one field - let's say setting a value to "ready for pickup", the assigned salesperson is automatically sent an e-mail.

We use a hosted Sharepoint setup, so I am hoping that this can be accomplished with notifications (I believe not), but perhaps by using a Workflow, which I have a limited understanding of.

Your help would be greatly appreciated, 
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark,

You can make a SharePoint Designer workflow on the list which runs when item is updated, and checks if the Order Status is "desired" for Current Item then shoots an email to salesperson assigned...

You can have a look at [Workflow Actions available in SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx) and [Workflow Conditions in SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-conditions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376962.aspx), some of them may not be there as you are using SharePoint Foundation...

But I guess you will be able to achieve your required tasks easily!

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that it could be accomplished this way - I will look into SharePoint Designer and have a crack at it. If I have a specific question on how to set it up properly, I will repost.